# Is there a way to set optional route location parts?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

firstly, I am not sure how to structure the question title correctly, feel free to edit it to represent the question correctly. I will try to explain what I mean.

I implemented localization on my app (URL of tutorial is at bottom of this post), and I have created my route as follows:

```
// Set language
Route::get('lang/{locale}', 'PagesController@lang');
```

And it works. But only on pages which have only one "level" in the url:

`example.com/first-level` - changing language **works** on these URLs
`example.com/first-level/second-level` - changing language **doesn't work** on these pages

At first I thought the problem is with url parameters, cause by chance, the pages where I first noticed changing language didn't work was on a url which has a route with an parameter like this

`example.com/first-level/{id}`

So then I tried to rewrite the route for changing languages to this (added an optional parameter)

```
// Set language
Route::get('lang/{optional?}/{locale}', 'PagesController@lang');
```

But that didn't work either

The language is changed by anchor tags which point to the route

```
<a href="lang/en">English</
<a href="lang/rs">Serbian</a>
```

Expected result: being able to change the language from whichever page the links are clicked. Clicking the links on pages like `example.com/one/two` and `example.com/one/{id}/two` are supposed to work.

Actual results: changing language works only on `example.com` and pages like `example.com/one` , and fails on `example.com/one/two` and `example.com/one/{id}/two` . When the links are clicked on these pages, the app is sent to an URL like this: `example.com/one/lang/en` and `example.com/one/{id}/lang/en` respectively.

I implemented localizations on my project following this tutorial https://appdividend.com/2019/04/01/how-to-create-multilingual-website-using-laravel-localization/#Step_2_Creating_Translation_Files

Comment: You'll have issues with an optional parameter that is not the last one in your URLs like that. It will treat what you'd expect `locale` to be as `optional`, since it goes by position of params. You can have an optional one at the end of the URL, but in the middle would require you to literally have `null` in your URL, like `example.com/lang/null/en`.

Comment: The route `lang/{optional?}/{locale}` was just a testing point. It didn't work so I have reverted it to `lang/{locale}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define both routes.

```php
Route::get('lang/{locale}', 'PagesController@locale');
Route::get('lang/{optional}/{locale}', 'PagesController@lang');
```

Then handle the optional variable with your controller methods.

```php
public function locale($locale)
{
    return $this->lang(null, $locale);
}

public function lang($optional, $locale)
{
    // ... your logic
}
```

As for your link problem, you need to use an absolute path.

```html
// relative path — https://yourdomain.com/current/path/lang/en
<a href="lang/en">English</a>
<a href="lang/rs">Serbian</a>

// absolute path — https://yourdomain.com/lang/en
<a href="/lang/en">English</a>
<a href="/lang/rs">Serbian</a>
```

Comment: I changed the links to absolute paths and that did the trick by itself, I totally overlooked that. Do you think I have to add a route with the optional parameter? Cause this works now as I wanted it to work

Comment: If you're satisfied that it's stable, then great!  You can always come back to this if you have issues.